# Set height of an image same as a neighboring element CSS

Tags: css, image, height, element

I was wondering how could you set height of an image to the neighboring elements height. So, essentially I want to have it like this:

[div] [img]

Other than javascript I can't see a way how can I do this. So, instead of using js can I just use CSS?

Thank you

Code so far(nothing special):

```
<div style="text-align:right;">
                        <label for="file-upload">Choose file</label>
                        <img><!-- Updates dynamically using js-->
                        <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="photo"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" />
                </div>
```

Comment: anycode ? ... look at flex box-model :)

Comment: Why not use javascript? Could you provide some more code?

Comment: @Paul because it is look. We use css for styling , js for behaviour. Separation is key for easy to maintain app and pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to style neighboring elements in CSS you can use adjacent selector(plus sign).
As in following:

```
label + img{height:300px}
```

That will target img in your code "after" any label.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/647Lsc46/)